# Installation of cc-tool on linux?

Tags: linux, installation, automake

I am trying to install cc-tool from this [link](https://github.com/dashesy/cc-tool) but nothing seems to happen when i run automake in the directory, can anybody tell me what i am doing wrong? When i run `automake -v` I get the following output:

```
automake: thread 0: reading autoconf --trace=AC_CONFIG_FILES:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_GNU_GETTEXT_INTL_SUBDIR:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_REQUIRE_AUX_FILE:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=_AM_COND_ELSE:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_PROG_CC_C_O:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_MAINTAINER_MODE:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_AUTOMAKE_VERSION:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_ENABLE_MULTILIB:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=_AM_COND_IF:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_FC_SRCEXT:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CONFIG_LINKS:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=_LT_AC_TAGCONFIG:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CONFIG_HEADERS:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_CONDITIONAL:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_GNU_GETTEXT:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_INIT:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_SUBST_TRACE:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_PROG_AR:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=_AM_SUBST_NOTMAKE:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=sinclude:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CANONICAL_TARGET:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_LIBSOURCE:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=m4_include:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CANONICAL_BUILD:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=m4_sinclude:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=LT_SUPPORTED_TAG:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CANONICAL_HOST:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AM_SILENT_RULES:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=AC_CONFIG_LIBOBJ_DIR:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}% --trace=_AM_COND_ENDIF:\$f:\$l::\$d::\$n::\${::}%
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/header-vars.am
automake: thread 0: reading Makefile.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/configure.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/progs.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/program.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/compile.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/depend2.am
automake: thread 0: Sources ending in .cpp become .o
automake: thread 0: Sources ending in .cpp become .obj
automake: thread 0: Sources ending in .cpp become .lo
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/lang-compile.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/libtool.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/texinfos.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/mans.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/inst-vars.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/mans-vars.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/tags.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/distdir.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/footer.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/install.am
automake: thread 0: reading /usr/share/automake-1.11/am/clean.am
automake: thread 0: creating ./Makefile.in
darth-speedious@darthspeedious-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~/Downloads/cc-tool-3eb$ ./Makefile.in
bash: ./Makefile.in: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to run autoreconf first,  It compiles all the relevant tools in the correct  order and installs the missing files.

```
autoreconf -vfi
```

You also seams to have some permission issue. Make sure that your user have proper permission.